# How to get image extension using file_get_contents php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to copy to my server an image from another site and i plan to use

```
<? 
file_put_contents($toPath, file_get_contents($fromPath));
?>
```

Ok, but to build the `$toPath` i need the extension of the file.
I know how to do it if the `$fromPath` is a normal path with name of the file at the end, but if i use a path like facebook uses `http://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?type=large`
how can i get the extension?

Thank you all.

Comment: To all that answer me, itryed: `$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME); // object oriented approach!
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($fromPath));  // e.g. gives "image/jpeg"
echo $mime_type; exit();

OR
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);

OR
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
echo finfo_file($finfo, $fromPath); ` NOTHING WORKS

Comment: To @Kolink this worked '$size = getimagesize($fromPath);
$extension = image_type_to_extension($size[2]);
echo $extension;'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$size = getimagesize($fromPath);
$extension = image_type_to_extension($size[2]);
```

Get the image size, grab the file type.

Comment: If you don't want to get the  dot before the extension (E.g.: ".png") Just add false as second parameter :image_type_to_extension($size[2], false);

Answer (score 5):

In PHP 5.3 you can use `finfo_file()`, see [PHP ref](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

```
file_put_contents($toPath, file_get_contents($fromPath));
$handle = fopen($toPath,'r');
print finfo_file($handle);
```

this works also for non images.

Answer (score 2):

This is way faster than @Kolink's answer:

```
$extension= end(explode("/", image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($photoURL))));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to guess or use mime types or magic bytes. The facebook graph api always returns jpegs (see [FB Profile Pic always returned as ".jpg"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850622/fb-profile-pic-always-returned-as-jpg) for some discussion).

But in general, here is a reference for smart file type detection: http://designshack.net/articles/php-articles/smart-file-type-detection-using-php/

If you have just a stream of bytes, [finfo_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) is your friend.

If you have a mime type, just use that.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that my PHP Version is 5.2.17 and finfo_file() just works in PHP >= 5.3.0...