# Are all Facebook profile pictures JPG?

Tags: php, facebook

I've been using the PHP GraphObject API from Facebook to get the URL of the user's profile picture, and was just wondering if ALL the Facebook profile pictures are .JPG's ...

I wanted to know this so that I know whether I need to determine the file type before saving it (using `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` etc).

Many thanks.

Comment: why don't you test it ... upload a non jpg picture to facebook and use the api to download the picture ... the answer my friend is blowing in the wind

Comment: Yeah I was just wondering if someone had a definitive answer ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [FB Profile Pic always returned as ".jpg"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850622/fb-profile-pic-always-returned-as-jpg)

Comment: definitive answer: yes

Comment: Ah yes ... It is a duplicate ... My bad. I did search but couldnt find that lol